# Regardless order, group by 3 columns and summarise in R

Tags: r, for-loop, combinations, plyr, stringr

In R, I am trying to sum over unique combinations of three columns regardless the order.
My reproducible example:

```
col1 <- c("pencil", "pencil",   "math", "math", "diet", "night")
col2 <- c("math",   "tree", "tree", "pencil",   "night",    "winter")
col3 <- c("tree",   "math", "pencil",   "tree", "winter",   "diet")
total <- c(3,   5,  10, 1,  1,  7)
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, total)
```

And the desired result is

```
col_out_1 <- c("math",  "winter")
col_out_2 <- c("tree",  "night")
col_out_3 <- c("pencil","diet")
eff <- c(19,8)
df_out <- data.frame(col_out_1, col_out_2, col_out_3, eff)
```

I got a list of unique combinations of the 3 columns (same as df_out) and united them into a single column, but can't find an efficient way to join it to the df

```
comb_uniq$combin <- df_out %>% paste(col_out_1, col_out_2, col_out_3, sep = "|" 


df[,5] <- case_when(str_detect(df$col1, comb_uniq$combin[1]) &
                       str_detect(te$regr_lib_Code.option.4, comb_uniq$combin[1]) &
                       str_detect(te$regr_lib_Code.option.5, comb_uniq$combin[1]) ~ paste(comb_uniq$combin[1]),
                     TRUE ~ "")
```

but this gives result only for one of the values
neither does the following for loop work

```
for (i in comb_uniq$combin) {
  df <- df %>% mutate(new = case_when(
    str_detect(df$col1, i) &
      str_detect(df$col2, i) &
      str_detect(df$col3, i) ~ i)
  )}
```

I need help to make those iterations work or try to find any other way to obtain the df_out. Thank you!

Please note that there are 220 unique combinations on the real data
and each column of the df contain approx 17 unique values

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with set membership (and element equality), regex on strings is really overkill and prone to problems. Instead, if you sort the columns first then you can naturally group on them.

```r
grps <- colnames(df)[1:3]
df[,grps] <- t(apply(df[,grps], 1, sort))
df
#   col1   col2   col3 total
# 1 math pencil   tree     3
# 2 math pencil   tree     5
# 3 math pencil   tree    10
# 4 math pencil   tree     1
# 5 diet  night winter     1
# 6 diet  night winter     7

aggregate(df[,!colnames(df) %in% grps], df[,grps], sum)
#   col1   col2   col3  x
# 1 math pencil   tree 19
# 2 diet  night winter  8
```

---

**Edit**

If there are any `NA`s in the data, it'll mess things up:

```r
t(apply(df[,grps], 1, sort))
#      [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]       
# [1,] Character,3 Character,3 Character,2 Character,3 Character,3 Character,3
```

Adding `na.last=TRUE` to `sort` fixes that:

```r
t(apply(df[,grps], 1, sort, na.last = TRUE))
#      [,1]   [,2]     [,3]    
# [1,] "math" "pencil" "tree"  
# [2,] "math" "pencil" "tree"  
# [3,] "math" "pencil" NA      
# [4,] "math" "pencil" "tree"  
# [5,] "diet" "night"  "winter"
# [6,] "diet" "night"  "winter"
```

We'll also need to modify the aggregation. Unfortunately, `NA`s in the grouping variables removes that row from consideration, so I'll fake an empty value (that is `NA` in your data) and then replace the `NA` with a blank string so that it is grouped appropriately.

```r
df$col3[3] <- NA
df[,grps] <- t(apply(df[,grps], 1, sort, na.last = TRUE))
tmpvar <- df[,grps]
tmpvar[is.na(tmpvar)] <- ""
tmpvar
#   col1   col2   col3
# 1 math pencil   tree
# 2 math pencil   tree
# 3 math   tree       
# 4 math pencil   tree
# 5 diet  night winter
# 6 diet  night winter

aggregate(df[,!colnames(df) %in% grps], tmpvar, sum)
#   col1   col2   col3  x
# 1 math   tree        10
# 2 math pencil   tree  9
# 3 diet  night winter  8
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer! it works on the example I gave, but when applied to original data I get the following error
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , grps, value = list(c(regr_lib_Code.option.3 = "Arts plastiques",  : 
  replacement element 1 has 3 rows, need 667
maybe my example does not reflect well th original. Each of the 3 columns to be combined contains 17 unique values

Comment: You can't assign this back into `df` because of the different number of rows.

Comment: I actually tried the apply part on the original dataset for now. It works perfectly on the example, i just need to find out why the first part of your solution does not work on my data

Comment: Interesting, perhaps there are nulls or something else. Try assigning `tmpvar <- t(apply(...))` and then compare `str(df[,grps])` with `str(tmpvar)` to see what is different about them. That might provide a clue as to what is going wrong.

Comment: You were right there were NAs, filtering them helped! Thank you!

Comment: If you have rows with an `NA` in one of the three columns,  you can use `t(apply(df[,grps], 1, sort, na.last = TRUE))` to preserve those rows, so that you don't need to filter them out.